# Calling stored procedure in Oracle database 12c I get invalid SQL statement

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, dapper

I have a stored procedure in an Oracle database 12c with params in and out, and when I run the code, I get an error that the SQL is not valid.

This is my code:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_connection.ConnectionString))
{  
    var parameters = new OracleDynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_SALES_REQUEST", OracleDbType.Int32 ,ParameterDirection.Input , 14478);
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_AMOUNT", OracleDbType.Int32 ,ParameterDirection.Input , 2500);
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_CURRENCY", OracleDbType.Char ,ParameterDirection.Input ,"YER", 3);
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_TP_CHANNEL", OracleDbType.Char ,ParameterDirection.Input ,"APP", 3);
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_ACC_TYPE", OracleDbType.Varchar2 ,ParameterDirection.Input ,"SUB"); 
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_MAIN_SRVC_ID", OracleDbType.Int32 ,ParameterDirection.Input ,1);
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_SUB_SRVC_ID", OracleDbType.Int32 ,ParameterDirection.Input ,1);  
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_INTERNAL_EXTRA1", OracleDbType.Varchar2 ,ParameterDirection.Input ,"123456"); 
    parameters.Add("in_RQ_INTERNAL_EXTRA2", OracleDbType.Varchar2 ,ParameterDirection.Input ,"775550902"); 
 
    // Add the out parameters to the OracleDynamicParameters object.
    parameters.Add("P_OUT_RESULT", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
    parameters.Add("P_OUT_RESULT_DESC", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);

    // Call the stored procedure.
    var result = connection.Execute("SP_INIT_SALES_REQUEST", parameters);

    // Retrieve the out parameter values from the OracleDynamicParameters object.
    // int outResult = parameters["out_Result"].Value<int>();
    // string outResultDesc = parameters["out_Result_Desc"].Value<string>();

    // Close the connection.
    connection.Close();

    return Ok("result =>" + result.ToString());
}
```

And I can not get the out params:

```
// Retrieve the out parameter values from the OracleDynamicParameters object.
// int outResult = parameters["out_Result"].Value<int>();
// string outResultDesc = parameters["out_Result_Desc"].Value<string>();
```

I try many times, but I get an error

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEUcP.png)

Comment: i upload the image can you see it ??

Comment: It sounds like Oracle doesn't know you want to call a procedure. I'm not familiar with what connectivity module you're using, but most of them require you to at least specify that it's a stored procedure rather than a normal SQL, and almost certainly would require you to actually define the parameter list. You'll have to chase down the docs for that software to learn how to do that. If it supports binds to PL/SQL blocks, you can usually do something like 'BEGIN procedurename(:col1,:col2,:col3,:outcol4); END;' and then set up the binds. But your software may be different.

Comment: What schema is the procedure `SP_INIT_SALES_REQUEST` in? If it is not in the same schema as the account you're logging in with you'll need to fully-qualify the name of the procedure, e.g. 'SOME_SCHEMA.SP_INIT_SALES_REQUEST`.

Comment: i have one schema in database So i did SCHEMA.SP_INIT_SALES_REQUEST , but do not works

Comment: Could you try to output the sql statement and run it in your oracle server ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure`:

```
    // Call the stored procedure.
    var result = connection.Execute("SP_INIT_SALES_REQUEST", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: i add it but not working :(